# How to connect to Heroku shield Postgres database from development machine via SSL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, ssl, heroku

We recently migrated to Heroku shield from normal Heroku server. Before that we were able to connect as SSL was not required.

We have a **Spring Boot** app which we need to connect to our **Postgres** database in Heroku shield server sometimes for debugging purposes.

We are able to connect to the database via **SSL** using PgAdmin using root.crt, postgresql.crt and postgresql.key files and providing the username and password after when I am connected to our VPN.

How can I connect to it from Sping Boot app while running from Eclipse ? I've read several documents but could not understand how to do this. Most of them suggested using OpenSSL.

I am using a windows machine.